# Truncate only older posts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, truncate

I have a simple do block here which truncates all my posts on index.html.erb. What I want to do is NOT truncate the most recent post at the top but truncate the rest below it so the bulk of the page is the most recent post. I know this is probably an easy fix for some but I can't seem to figure it out. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
</div>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
      <p><%= truncate(post.body, :length => 300) %></p>
      <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: off topic: I would avoid using `strftime` directly when formatting dates and times in your views; use `I18n.localize` and put your formats in `config/locals/*.yml` see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: I will take that into consideration. Thanks. I may move the logic out of the view anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<div>
  <% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
    <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
    <p><%= index.zero? ? post.body : truncate(post.body, length: 300) %></p>
    <p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea with the index idea. Hadn't thought of that. Thanks.